# PHP Function - Compare Transcript Arrays

Tags: php, algorithm

I need to write a function that can takes a $correct array and a $guess array.  The function needs to compare the array elements of $guess to $correct and match them up as closely as possible, returning a $result array.  If the $guess array has more elements than $correct, some elements may not match up and need to be dropped.  If the $guess array has less elements than $correct, some elements might need to be blank.

This function is used to compare a known transcript of Chinese characters to a guessed transcript to figure out which characters are correct or incorrect.  The $result can then be compared, character by character to $correct to know which specific character positions match or don't match.

For example:

```
function compare($correct, $guess);
//returns $result

$correct = ['你', '昨', '天', '为', '什', '么', '没', '跟', '我', '们', '打', '游', '戏', '我', '昨', '天', '一', '点', '时', '间', '都', '没', '有', '我', '一', '直', '在', '写', '作', '业', '那', '你', '现', '在', '写', '好', '了', '吗', '周', '末', '有', '时', '间', '吧', '写', '好', '了', '但', '是', '我', '周', '末', '要', '复', '习'];

$guess   = ['你', '昨', '天', '为', '什', '么', '没', '给', '我', '们', '打', '游', '戏', '规', '则', '天', '一', '点', '时', '间', '都', '没', '有', '我', '一', '直', '在', '写', '作', '业', '你', '数', '学', '好', '了', '吗', '周', '末', '有', '时', '间', '吧', '写', '好', '了', '但', '是', '我', '周', '末', '要', '复', '习'];
```

Should return:

```
$result  = ['你', '昨', '天', '为', '什', '么', '没', '给', '我', '们', '打', '游', '戏', '规', '则', '天', '一', '点', '时', '间', '都', '没', '有', '我', '一', '直', '在', '写', '作', '业', ' ', '你', '数', '学', ' ', '好', '了', '吗', '周', '末', '有', '时', '间', '吧', '写', '好', '了', '但', '是', '我', '周', '末', '要', '复', '习'];
```

Notes

- Elements 7, 13, 14 don't match
- Elements 30, 34 are in the $correct but not $guess

I'm not really sure where to start on this.  I can solve it manually, but trying to write an algorithm becomes tricky because the $guess array might have one or more incorrect characters in a row, or it may miss a character completely, or add a character that doesn't exist.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php are probably the first place to start, ability to compare two arrays.

Comment: @Scuzzy I'm not so concerned about getting which elements are present or not present in the arrays, that's fairly straight-forward.  The challenge comes in when there's an extra element (or more) on one of the arrays which throws off the positioning.

Comment: From your current data, it is not 7, 15, 16 don't match but 7, 13, 14, 30 and many more are also not matched (including things in `$correct` but not in `$guess`).  Check your data again carefully because it is currently can't compare into your notes.

Comment: Run this code in your browser (code is in https://onlinephp.io/c/cbc8d ) to compare it visually and see that there are nothing work as your notes.

Comment: Updated version: https://onlinephp.io/c/a9628

Comment: @vee Sorry, you're right, it was 7,13,14 that don't match.  The others do match up, if they're shifted over by one at position 30 and 34.  This is the crux of why this is so difficult to write.

Comment: The array index 7, 13, 14 no match, you use `$guess` value. But index 30, 34 also no match you use empty space instead. I don't see any rules for these.

Comment: Is this a [mcve]?  These sample arrays seem needlessly long, no?  I don't understand the algorithm rules based on the example.

Comment: @BlkStormy perhapps where the different indexes are you need to start slicing the remainder of the arrays and start the comparison again for the remainder of the array, there's probably going to be some dirty looping to try to match chunks of data.